# Geometry node only distributed on specific area

Tags: particles, geometry, geometry-nodes

Im trying to create a globe with some spheres coming out of it ( geometry node ) but I only want them to appear on land and not on the ocean. Any ideas on how to only distribute the point in the Continents?
[image: Globe]

Comment: Hello, could you add some information about the globe : Is it done using a mesh or a texture, uv coordinates or generated coordinates, etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this e.g. with a texture like this:

[image]

Comment: Nice! Thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left to my answer. Thank you!!